# What is the difference between the otolith membrane and the endolymph?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, histology, human-ear

The human vestibular system contains otoliths to sense acceleration in the vertical and horizontal plane. I cannot find what the difference is between the otolith membrane and the endolymph?

Can anyone show them where they are located in a picture?

It seems they are different as wikipedia has two different entries for them. See for example the two pictures [here](https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/96/14296-004-75118A1C.jpg) and [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Bigotolith.jpg/500px-Bigotolith.jpg) - I cannot pick the difference.

Comment: Instead of downvote, please explain what is wrong with the question. My background is math not biology.

Comment: I suspect it is because it's not clear why you think they are the same thing, so the question is whether you have adequately tried to understand them before asking.

Comment: @kmm, I understand nothing from biology and anatomy and I will not understand them later too. It is like asking you to try understanding optimal control theory or Algebraic Riccati Equations. I just would like to make sure I am not writing a wrong annotation in a report which contains a human anatomy. This is totally irrelevant to my topic.

Comment: @kmm, These photos [A](https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/96/14296-004-75118A1C.jpg) and [B](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Bigotolith.jpg/500px-Bigotolith.jpg) cause I feel they are the same things.

Comment: Don't blame me. I was just speculating as to the downvote. You say you will never understand biology, but you are trying to do just that right now. So I think it is incumbent on you to do what you say you won't do. I actually do understand optimal control theory, because I needed to for a project I was working on. I didn't know anything about it, so I did my "homework" to learn what I needed to learn. I suspect the downvoter expected the same of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two pictures you provide in the question (Fig. 2 and 3 below) actually show it all. You just didn't got the scale right. The question shows prior research effort and the inner ear is a complex organ indeed.

Fig. 1 shows a macro-scale overview image of the inner ear, or the labyrinth. The two otoliths are called the sacculus & utriculus, who sense accelerations in the horizontal and vertical planes.

Now if we zoom in on the sacculus you get Fig. 2, which you provided in the question (comment). Here you can see that the hair cells (the sensory cells) are bathed in **[endolymph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endolymph)**, which is the fluid contained in the membranous labyrinth of the inner ear.

Now if we zoom in further to the cellular level we can see the sensory parts of the sacculus (Fig. 3). In the figure you will recognize the other structure you are referring to, namely the otolithic membrane. The otoliths contain small grainy crystalline structures called otoconia. Otoconia move in response to acceleration, because of their inertia. When they move with respect of their surroundings they activate the hair cells. The otoconia are embedded in a jelly like matrix, called [otolithic membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otolithic_membrane). the endolymph surrounds the region above the otoconia in Fig. 3.

[image: Labyrinth]
<sup>Fig. 1. Overview of the inner ear. source: [Dizziness & Balance](http://www.dizziness-and-balance.com/disorders/bppv/otoliths.html)</sup>

[image]
<sup>Fig. 2. Sacculus. source: Wikimedia</sup>

[image]
<sup>Fig. 3. Sacculus - close up sensory structures. source: Wikimedia</sup>

Comment: Many thanks. Just another question. Is otoconia the same bone people take out of fish and call it otolith?